# Laravel API Resource Collection return specific fields from other resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-api

I am working on an api that will be accessible via a mobile app.

I have defined resources and collections for respective endpoints. My problem is now is that I want to return different api json data based on what ever collection.

**Here is an example**

Provinces has cities and suburbs, so in json format I need to have

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Eastern Cape",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "name": "Alice"
                },
            ],
            "suburbs": [
                    "name": "Suburb 1"
            ]
        },
]
```

I want different data when the cities resource is called in news api collection

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Eastern Cape",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "name": "Alice",
                    "municipality": "municipality name",
                },
            ],
            "suburbs": [
                    "name": "Suburb 1",
                    "ward_number": "ward 1"
            ]
        },
]
```

**This is an NewsResource Api**

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id'=> $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'content' => $this->content,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'category_id' => $this->news_category_id,
            'featured_image' => url($this->featured_image),
            'author' => new UserResource($this->user),
            'category' => new NewsCategoryResource($this->category), //Only category Name to be displayed
            'municipality' => new MunicipalityResource($this->municipality), // Only Municipality Name to be displayed
            'comments' => new NewsCommentResource($this->comments),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: So api route `api/foo/` is going to return your first json and `api/bar` is going to return your second json as an example?

Comment: Yes,  both are using different api end points

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what is your code structure, but hope this help for you

You may use different queries, for example

```
/** For the obvious resource calling */
return SomeResource::collection (SomeModel::with(['suburbs', 'cities'])
    /** Other filter queries */
    ->get());

/** For the cities resource calling */
return SomeResource::collection (SomeModel::with(['suburbs:id,ward_number', 'cities:id,municipality'])
    /** Other filter queries */
    ->get());
```

In your Resource class which you use for the cities/suburbs data, do it like so

```
return [
    /** Some data which you need */
    'municipality' => $this->when($this->municipality !== null, $this->municipality),
    'ward_number' => $this->when($this->ward_number !== null, $this->ward_number),
];
```